# SSIS Expression to get Year and previous Quarter generates error "Truncation occurred during evaluation of expression'

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS job that creates flat files and I need to include the Year and Quarter in the filename. Since I will be reporting on the previous quarter I need the quarter to be the previous quarter. I'm running into two problems.

The first problem is my expression is giving me an error message that states " A truncation occurred during evaluation of the expression".

```
"TPSReport_"
+ (DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(GETDATE()) + "Q" 
+ RIGHT("00"+ (DT_WSTR,2) DATEADD("qq", -1, GETDATE()),2) +
 ".txt"
```

Second, I'm not sure how to handle reporting for quarter 4. Since the expression returns the current year it will be incorrect when Q4 reports are produced during Q1 of the new year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's failing in your expression is this portion

```
(DT_WSTR,2) DATEADD("qq", -1, GETDATE())
```

If you change that 2 to 240, you'll see the generated value looks like "2023-02-22 11:11:41.267000000" so the error makes sense as it is truncating the string and you didn't explicitly ask for truncation.

I think what you meant was to then call the DATEPART

```
(DT_WSTR,2) DATEPART("QQ", DATEADD("qq", -1, GETDATE()))
```

That will generate a 1/2/3/4 values

I find it helpful to break problems down into smaller components. Especially given the lack of debug-ability of SSIS Expressions. Creating multiple Variable is a handy approach as you can identify where a thing goes wrong much easier

### Variables

- `SourceDate` data type Date initialized to 1/1/2023. We'll eventually tie this to the current date but we need to be able to test boundary conditions
- `PreviousQuarterDate` data type Date. In the Expression section, use your existing logic of `DATEADD("QQ", -1, @[User::SourceDate])`  It should show "10/1/2022"
- `PreviousQuarterQuarterName` data type String Expression of `"Q" + RIGHT("00" + (DT_WSTR,2) DATEPART("QQ", @[User::PreviousQuarterDate] ), 2)`  This will generate a value like Q01/Q02/Q03/Q04 based on the previously solved problem of "what's the previous quarter"
- `PreviousQuarterYearName` data type String expression of `(DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(@[User::PreviousQuarterDate])` This also uses our previous quarter date to build the 4 digit year as a string.
- `ReportName` data type String This expression is simplified to just be straight string concatenation `"TPSReport_" + @[User::PreviousQuarterYearName] +  @[User::PreviousQuarterQuarterName] + ".txt"` which shows a value of "TPSReport_2022Q04.txt"

You can see how you can further genericize this approach by creating a BaseFileName variable and FileExtension with values of "TPSReport_" and ".txt" and now you can use the same bits of logic across all your packages (assuming this is a standard naming convention)

At this point, if everything looks good, I'd update `SourceDate` to be 4/1/2023, 8/9/2023 and 11/18/2023 (pick random dates in each quarter to ensure the Quarter logic behaves as expected).

If all that looks good, then click the Expression ellipses `...` on the SourceDate variable to be `@[System::StartTime]` It's virtually identical to GETDATE except StartTime remains consistent for the entire execution of the package whereas if the package started at 2023-03-31T11:59:59.997 the initial value of ReportName would be "TPSReport_2022Q04.txt" but as time progresses and the clock ticks over to 1 April, the value of ReportName becomes "TPSReport_2023Q01.txt"  Whereas using StartTime would always report a value of  2023-03-31T11:59:59.997